# phpmyadmin file upload max size is peculiarly -2,147,483,648B

Tags: phpmyadmin, php-ini, laragon

I am trying to setup a new working environment for a temporary period. After installing `laragon (v4.0.16)` and setting up `phpmyadmin`, when I tried to import a project database, I see that the file upload size is peculiarly **-2,147,483,648B**. See below image:

[image: see this image]

I checked `php.ini` and the settings are: `post_max_size=2G` and `upload_max_filesize=2G`

I can't find the reason why max upload size is strangely **-2,147,483,648B**

Any suggestion or advice will be appreciable on how to solve this.

***Note:***
Notifying those who are curious why I installed laragon 4 that [laragon.org](https://laragon.org) is down and can't find laragon 5 or 6 anywhere else.

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you using? This could be a bug in phpMyAdmin

Comment: I was using phpMyAdmin 5.2.0 (latest stable).... I had to manage laragon 6 from a friend and after installing that that problem was solved